# Is the electric fence from “The Last of Us” (2023) series realistic?

Tags: realism, the-last-of-us

In episode 3 of *The Last of Us* TV series, Bill, a lonely survivalist, makes several traps around his place. He has a perimeter electric fence that is apparently powered by a generator or stationary batteries.

Could it work in real life as effectively as it did in the series — where it easily held and fried invaders?

[image: Bill and his electric fence behind him]

Comment: > Electric Fence Netting "Plus-Minus" the *individual* horizontal lines of the netting are *alternately connected* to the fence and earth lead of the energiser. https://www.patura.com/App/WebObjects/XSeMIPSPatura.woa/cms/page/locale.enUS/pid.102.104.954/agid.307.322.3240/ecm.ag/Electric-Fence-Netting-Plus-Minus.html

Comment: With a generator, yes : (Ever been 'bit' by a spark plug? Not pleasant.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_fence - w/o there being two *separate* poles for you to complete the circuit of, like there isn't in the simple hardware cloth fence pictured, no. Not unless it was extremely well insulated from ground and pushing enough amps to go through your shoes.